# Excel: How to perform an XLOOKUP by using a column value as a search parameter

Tags: excel, datatables, transpose, xlookup

In excel, I have the following table:

| Month | Year | ProjectID | 1-23 | 2-23 | ... 12-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2023 | 14404 | $210 | $630 | $3000 |
| 10 | 2023 | 15023 | $250 | $420 | $5000 |

The monthly columns in the table represents monthly forecasts/actuals for each projects throughout the year (1-23 to 12-23). The Month and year columns represent the month in which the data was retrieved and they get updated each month and would look something like this:

| Month | Year | ProjectID | 1-23 | 2-23 | ... 11-23 | 12-2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2023 | 14404 | $210 | $630 | $450 | $3000 |
| 11 | 2023 | 15023 | $250 | $420 | $500 | $5000 |

Let's say I wanted to perform a search for the forecast/actual value for a specific month and year using the `xlookup` function. Using the month and year columns (which are subject to change) how can I perform an `xlookup` to search for the monthly actual/forecast for the month that I'm in (i.e. if the Month is "11", and the year is "2023", I want to get the forecast/actual value in the [11-23] for each project.)?

Comment: It's unclear to me if the year and month input values for your search are in cells, or to be entered in the lookup formula. Also what was the version of the `XLOOKUP`-formula you used? What did it return versus what you expected? Also is mentioned table an actual table, or just a range. In latter case, are the headers text or dates?

Comment: Are the column headers 1-23, 2-23, etc. text strings? Or are they dates formatted as "m-yy"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example and modify it to meet your needs:

[image: filter_xlookup.png]

The values to filter by Month and Year in this example are located in cells `A8` and `B8` respectively, and the formula used in cell `A10` is:

```
=LET(
   val, TEXT(DATE(B8, A8, 1), "m-yy"),
   hdr, HSTACK(A1:C1, val),
   arr, HSTACK(A2:C5, XLOOKUP(val, TEXT(D1:O1, "m-yy"), D2:O5)),
   VSTACK(hdr, FILTER(arr, (INDEX(arr,, 1)=A8)*(INDEX(arr,, 2)=B8)))
)
```

This formula assumes the values in the header range `D1:O1` are dates with custom formatting "m-yy" applied. The `TEXT` function is used to convert the values to text strings, so the `XLOOKUP` function can return a match.

If the values in the header range `D1:O1` are already text, then simply use `XLOOKUP(val, D1:O1, D2:O5)` to achieve the same results.